# Is there any way to calculate individual equation in a column using R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where I have a column name Rooms which holds the number of rooms in the house. It has about 50,000+ rows and I checked it using `str(df$Rooms)` and it is a factor with 44 levels. The column looks like this :

```
>str(df$Rooms)
Factor w/ 44 levels "","1","1+1","1+2",..: 20 32 23 27 28 29 27 23 26 24 ...

> df$Rooms
1+2
3
1+3
1+2
4
3
1+1
2
..
..
```

My question is there any way or any functions or library in R that can be used to get the value of these equations. Maybe so that it can become something like this :

```
 > df$Rooms
    3
    3
    4
    3
    4
    3
    2
    2
    ..
    ..
```

Thank you in advance~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `eval` `parse`

```
df$final_rooms <- sapply(as.character(df$Rooms), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
df

#  Rooms final_rooms
#1   1+2           3
#2     3           3
#3   1+3           4
#4   1+2           3
#5     4           4
#6     3           3
#7   1+1           2
#8     2           2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Rooms = structure(c(2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
4L), .Label = c("1+1", "1+2", "1+3", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thank you because it worked. May I know what is `function(x)` and `eval` `parse` specifically? Or rather, what does it do?

Thank you in advance again~

Comment: @Lutfi Since `eval(parse(text = x))` is used to evaluate string into R code. Test few examples `eval(parse(text = '2 + 2'))` Or `eval(parse(text = 'mtcars'))`. Since it can handle only 1 value at a time, we use `sapply` to give 1 input at a time and `function(x)` is used as anonymous function call for each of `df$Rooms` value.

Answer (score 0):

We can split by the `+` and do a `sum` after converting to `numeric` without using the `eval(parse` in `base R`

```
df$final_rooms <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Rooms) , "+", 
       fixed = TRUE), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
```

---

Or another option is to read with `read.table` into two columns and do a `rowSums` with vectorized option

```
df$final_rooms <- rowSums(read.table(text = as.character(df$Rooms), 
         sep="+", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
df$final_rooms
#[1] 3 3 4 3 4 3 2 2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Rooms = structure(c(2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
4L), .Label = c("1+1", "1+2", "1+3", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```